# copy-item issue in powershell

Tags: powershell, copy-item

```
Copy-Item -Path "\\100.00.00.00\\Folders 17-11-2015\Some.db" -Destination (New-Item -Path "\\100.00.00.00\folder" -ItemType Directory -Name (Get-Date -f dd_MM_yyyy)) -force -recurse
```

Hi, does anybody have any idea why the file/files are not actually copied, i get a 'the file exists error' if i put verbose on it just seems like its copied and the folder gets created but has no contents?

I have tried copying the whole contents of the folder and it shows the files copying across in verbose output yet nothing is in the destination folder? I defaced the real addresses obviously but just to add, the source and destination are on the same file-server.

Really weird and totally thrown me here, always the simple things.

any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance,

R

Comment: You're trying to copy a single file, so using `-Recurse` doesn't make sense. Also, did you try doing it in two steps (create the destination folder before copying something to it)? And why are you doing a remote-to-remote copy instead of running the script on the actual host?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new directory each time this command is executed. If you have it in a loop or if this was executed before, you will get item exists error for the folder from `new-item` cmdlet. Recommandation is break this into two pieces and `test-path` before you create the folder.